# Efficient way to perform calculation

Tags: c#

I am trying to find the best way to handle the below:

1. I have a List of Decimals
2. The list is not fixed....meaning I could have 2 one time and 9 another
3. I want build a new list of decimals using the algorithm below

I am really struggling with the most efficient way to perform this operation. I am really trying to cut down on the amount of times I have to loop over the data. Is there an obvious approach I am just glossing over?

Any suggestions on a possible path forward would be much appreciated.

---

```
  new #1 = #1
  new #2 = #2 * (1 - #1)
  new #3 = #3 * (1 - #1) * (1 - #2) 
  new #4 = #4 * (1 - #1) * (1 - #2) * (1 - #3)
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In-place replacement:

```
List<decimal> data =....
decimal multiplier = 1.0;
for (var i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
{
   var oldMultipleir = multiplier;
   multiplier *= (1 - data[i]);
   data[i] *= oldMultiplier;
}
```